# How long does it take a postcard to get from USA to Germany?

Tags: mail, shipping

I am sending a postcard from a large US city to a large city in Germany via the cheapest shipping option.

How long should the letter take to arrive? I have read 5 to 10 business days in one place and 10 to 12 business days in another place. Is there a definitive answer? It is hard to find this information on the USPS website.

(Note: you can use this calculator for the reverse trip: https://www.portokalkulator.de/portokalkulator/std)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not appear to be about travel in the scope defined in the [help].

Comment: We can talk about this in meta, but there are quite a large number of other questions on the site relating to international shipping speeds for other destinations and the answers seem hard to find.

Comment: I've edited the description to reference a postcard, which is something a traveler from Germany to the USA might want to send home.

Comment: @KevinBurke also, there used to be trend (googling `pre sending luggage` suggests the trend is still going) where travellers send their luggage to their destination beforehand so they wouldn't have to accompany it. Not really related to postcards, but that's certainly related to travel.

Comment: I have seen reports of items arriving by mail within 48 hours and also outside 3 months from sending, so hard to give a good answer.

Comment: It really varies. When I tried from Singapore to India, it arrived in a week. Tried from Malaysia (which is closer), and it was around a month.

Comment: USPS only gives estimated times for expedited services, i.e. Priority Mail and faster. From experience I would expect 2-3 weeks for a postcard from the US to an EU member state.

Comment: Given that postcards are pretty much only sent by travellers, I'm voting to keep this open.

Comment: Given that postcards are pretty much only sent by travellers, I'm voting to keep this open _again_. How many times, people?

Answer (score 34):

Since 2007, I received 53 postcards from the US (via postcrossing). I live in Germany, so this is relevant to your question. 
The average travel time was 11 days, roughly 67% arrived within this time frame. The minimum was 3 days, the maximum 61.

Of course, these are not 100% exact numbers - the "send" date is the day the sender got my address, not necessarily the day he mailed the card, and the "received" date is the day I registered the card, not necessarily the day it reached my mailbox.

Still, all those numbers will always be only estimates, and every single postcard can arrive late. In 2016, I mailed three postcards from Scotland to Germany. The first card arrived after about one week, the second one after two weeks, the third one after three weeks. Since I dropped them all into the SAME mailbox at the very same time, I have no clue why the travel time differed so much...

Comment: yeah. Longest I've ever had mail from the US take to Europe was 9 months. It'd been addressed correctly, but the mail sorting people in the US had misplaced it into a bag for the wrong country, and from there it traveled through like 20 countries before getting to me (the collection of postmarks and writing redirecting it was interesting).

Comment: @jwenting There's this image of a parcel meant for Australia that's first been sent to Austria 5 times. https://i.redd.it/o761lf0fk7021.jpg Apparently it happens so often that the Austrian postal service has a special stamp for the occasion.

Comment: @Nzall I don’t think this stamp is especially for parcels that should go to Australia and end up in Austria...

Comment: I'm impressed and amazed that you kept track of the delivery time!

Answer (score 1):

Of the 20 postcards I have sent through post crossing to Germany, on average it takes 19 days for them to get there. Of the 5 postcards I have received from Germany it has taken, on average, 53 days. I don't know why there is such a big difference.